# ASP.NET Chart: How to restrict y dimension to a fix range such as 0 to 10?

Tags: asp.net, charts

The y dimension of my data goes only from 0 to 10. But as default my chart automatically extends the range of y to include negative values and displays a range, for example, from minus 1 to 20.

If I want the y scale to go only from 0 to 10. How do I specify this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify [`Minimum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum.aspx) and [`Maximum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum.aspx) for `AxisY`

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server"...
    ...
    <asp:ChartArea ... >
         <AxisY Title="Some Title" Minimum="0" Maximum="10"> </AxisY>
         ...
```